# Proof that the smallest inductive set in an ordered integral domain has the well ordering property

Tags: real-analysis

I am not sure whether my proof is correct.

$N$ is the intersection of all inductive sets (a set such that $1$ (the multiplicative identity) is an element of it and if $x$ is an element of it then $x+1$ is an element of it) in an ordered integral domain $R$. Suppose there exists a nonempty subset $M \subseteq N$ such that $M$ doesn't have a least element. Then since the smallest element of $N$ is $1$ (this is true since $\{\, x\in R \mid  x \ge 1  \,\}$ is an inductive set therefore $N$ is a subset of it) it isn't an element of $M$. Suppose $x \not\in M$ then $x+1 \not\in M $ or $x+1 \in M$. If $x+1 \in M$ then there exists $\alpha \in M$ such that $\alpha < x+1$ therefore the element $x+1$ can be excluded from $M$ (I am most unsure about this part specifically) and it will still be a non-empty set without a least element. Thus $x+1 \not\in M$. However the preceding argument shows that $N \setminus M$ is an inductive set, therefore $N \setminus M = N$ which means that $M = \emptyset$ which is a contradiction. Therefore all nonempty subsets of $N$ contain a least element.

Comment: Perhaps clarify what you mean by an inductive set here? Since I would imagine that the set $\{x\in \mathbb{N} | x\geq n\} $ is an inductive set for any $n$ with the successor given by $s(x) = x+1$ but clearly the intersection of all of these is the empty set

Comment: Also there is a mistake in concluding that since $N\subseteq \{x \in R| x\geq 1 \}$ we must have $1\in N$. You have the definition of subset the wrong way around, or more concretely, $\emptyset$ is also a subset of $\{x\in R|x\geq 1\} $ but clearly $1\notin \emptyset $

Comment: An inductive set satisfies two properties: 1. $1$ (the multiplicative identity) is in it; 2. if $x$ is in it then $x+1$ is also in it.

Comment: $N$ is the intersection of all inductive sets, therefore if $\{\,x \in R \mid x\ge 1\,\}$ is an inductive set (which it is), then it is included in the intersection, therefore $N$ is a subset of it which means all elements of $N$ are $\ge 1$

Comment: “ and it will still be a non-empty set without a least element.” Is this contradicting something?  It seems like (from your next sentence) you are suggesting that this is a contradiction, but I’m not sure why.  We never said $M$ had to be minimal in any sense, did we?

Comment: By excluding $x+1$ from $M$ (if it is an element of it) whenever $x$ isn't in $M$, I am proving that $N \setminus M$ is an inductive set ($1$ is already an element of it). Which then implies $M = \emptyset$ which contradicts the proposition that $M$ is non empty. I could assume that $M$ is the minimal nonempty subset without a least element, but it wouldn't change anything since by using the same arguments it would lead to the same contradiction that it is empty.

Comment: @user1180027 I understand how you are trying to prove $N\backslash M$ is inductive and get a contradiction from that - but in order to do that, you need to first establish that $x\notin M\implies x+1\notin M$.  And in doing that, you seem to be arguing by contradiction for that step as well.  And for that step, there is no apparent contradiction.

Comment: @user1180027 Also, you cannot assume $M$ is minimal among nonempty subsets without a least element, not without showing that such a minimal nonempty subset exists first - taking the intersection of all such sets is not a priori going to be such a set.

Answer (score 1):

> therefore the element $x+1$ can be excluded from M (I am most unsure about this part specifically) and it will still be a non-empty set without a least element. Thus
> $x+1 \not\in M$.

This does not seem to follow, as you have no reason to think $M$ is minimal among non-empty sets without least elements.  Thus you haven't shown anything contradictory about $x+1\in M$.

To prove this (without using well-ordering or induction from $\mathbb N$ since that is kind of cheating and would defeat the purpose of the problem), we let $N$ be the intersection of all inductive sets as you already did in your proof. We want to first establish that every element $x\in N$ has an immediate successor in $x+1$, i.e., $\{y\in N \mid x<y<x+1\}=\emptyset$. (For brevity we will in the future simply say “has an immediate successor”,  implicitly requiring that this successor be $x+1$.)

To prove this, let $T$ be the set of elements of $N$ such that every preceding element has an immediate successor.  We observe that $1\in T$, vacuously, since as you have observed in the main post $1$ is the smallest element of $N$.  Moreover, if $x\in T$, then we claim $x$ has an immediate successor as well, since if not, the set $\{y\in N\mid y\leq x \text{ or } y\geq x + 1\}$ is a smaller inductive set.
From this, it follows that every element preceding $x+1$ has an immediate successor, and so $x+1\in T$.  Thus $T$ is an inductive set, and so $T=N$.

Now we prove the main result.

If $M\subseteq N$ has no least element, then let $T'=\{x\in N\mid\forall m\in M,\,  x<m \}$.  Certainly $1\in T'$, otherwise $1$ would lie in $M$ and be the least element.

On the other hand, if $x\in T'$, then for each $m\in M$, we have $x<m$, which implies $x+1\leq m$.  Now $x+1\notin M$, as otherwise it would be the least element.  It follows that the inequality is strict for all $m\in M$, and thus $x+1\in T'$.

Thus $T'$ is an inductive set, so $T'=N$.  But $T'$ is clearly disjoint from $M$, and since $M\subseteq N=T'$, we have $M=\emptyset$.

Comment: I don't understand how you define $R$. Is it: if $x \in R$ then for all $y \in N$ such that $y<x$ there exists an immediate succesor $y' \in N$ meaning there are no $z \in N$ satisfying $y<z<y'$?

Comment: @user1180027 Well, more specifically, for all $y<x$, $y+1$ is an immediate successor, meaning there is no $z\in N$ satisfying $y<z<y+1$.

Comment: Why is $\{\, y\in N \mid  y \le x \, \mathrm{ or } \, y \ge x+1  \,\}$ an inductive set?

Comment: (Disregard my deleted comment, there was no mistake and it should indeed be $N$) 
 If $S=\{\, y\in N \mid  y \le x \, \mathrm{ or } \, y \ge x+1  \,\}$, then to see $S$  is inductive note that it contains $1$, and if $y\in S$ just verify $y+1\in S$ case by case: if $y<x$ then the immediate successor condition implies $y+1\leq x$, whereas if $y\geq  x$ then $y+1\geq x+1$.

Comment: @user1180027 it’s possible the confusion stems from my use of $R$ to denote an inductive set - I seem to have forgotten that $R$ was already used for our integral domain.  I’ve changed it to $T$ for clarity.